# Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'func' before initialization

Tags: javascript, react-redux, reduce

i have a problem with a function, the second time it is executed the console return the error 'Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'total' before initialization'. The sum of the values seams ok, but i cant find why the function is giving this error.`

```
 sumExpenses = () => {
    const { expenses } = this.props;
    const total = expenses.reduce((acc, e) => {
      const parc = (Number(e.value) * Number(e.exchangeRates[e.currency].ask)).toFixed(2);
      const final = Number(parc) + Number(acc);
      console.log(final);
      return total;
    }, 0);
  };
```

`The error:`

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'total' before initialization
    at WalletForm.js:31:1
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at WalletForm.sumExpenses (WalletForm.js:27:1)
    at WalletForm.handleClick (WalletForm.js:18:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:4291:1)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:9041:1)
    at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (react-dom.development.js:9073:1)
```

`

Im trying to apply a table of exchange prices to as expenses app through redux. The values looks right on the state, but the navigator give me an error when i add the second expense.

Comment: You are calling `return total` inside `reduce` callback which doesn't make any sense since `total` is the result of that `reduce`. I guess  that you wanted to return `final`

Comment: But when i put final on return, VScode give me the error 'total' is assigned but nerver used. I couldn't find a way to remove it, any tips? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Because you probably want to use it. I guess that `sumExpenses` should return something so `return total` after the `reduce`

Comment: Thanks man, i was really confused by the error.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are logging `final` but returning `total`.

```
 sumExpenses = () => {
    const { expenses } = this.props;
    const total = expenses.reduce((acc, e) => {
      const parc = (Number(e.value) * Number(e.exchangeRates[e.currency].ask)).toFixed(2);
      const final = Number(parc) + Number(acc);
      console.log(final);
      return final ;
    }, 0);

    return total
  };
```

Comment: I was really confused here, thanks!!!!!